# What steps to take to resize an existing MYSQL NDB Cluster?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I have an existing NDB Cluster. It's grown larger than I expected and I need to make it bigger. When I ask the management console for the ALL REPORT MEMORY, it looks like the datamemory is 65% full. However, I get page faults, swap, and memory related issues.

How do I find what my correct settings for data-memory, index-memory and any other related parameters should be?

Is ndb_size.pl the correct script to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data nodes are up and running you can check the
size of the virtual memory allocated to the data node. If
this is bigger than 80-90% of your available memory you will
experience issues like you describe.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael, to confirm that means if I have 1GB of available memory, then I cannot use more than 80-90% of 1GB of virtual memory? This does seem to fit my problem.

Comment: yep, correct for NDB data node processes